# How to rename a worksheet based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

How can I rename a sheet using  based on cell A1 value from sheet 2.
I tried the following code:

```vb
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Sheet1.Name = Sheet2.Range("A1").Value
    End Sub
```

but if I use

```
Sheets(1).Name = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value
```

or

```
Sheets("Sheet1") = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
```

it works but I need to use code name of the sheets so when I rename sheet 2 the code would still work.

Comment: 'I want...' isn't really a question on a platform primarily based around answering code-based questions. You are more likely to recieve help if you show your own attempt and tell us where it errors out/won't work as expected. Please see [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your `Sheets(1).Name = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value` statement will work, no matter the name of sheet 2.

Comment: What if i insert a sheet in between?

Comment: @cristim so are you looking to set `.Name` of first sheet to always the `[A1]` of second sheet, or of the last sheet? Or of a specifcally named sheet? It can only be one of those 3

Comment: What doesn't work in your first example? The code works fine for me. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Of course the first attempt `Sheet1.Name = Sheet2.Range("A1").Value` should work! If not, then there was either / nothing in cell A1 / one of the 7 forbidden characters in A1 / A1 value length above 31 / sheet name already existing / no sheet with codenname `Sheet2` / no sheet with codenname `Sheet1` / ....

Comment: Yes it works indeed. I must have dove something wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

In general I found your question very unclear, but here are the 3 possible interpretations:

1. Set first `Sheet` as the `[A1]` of the 2nd `Sheet`.

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
         If Not IsEmpty(Sheets(2).Range("A1"))
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1")
         End If
   End Sub
   ```
2. Set first `Sheet` as the `[A1]` of the last `Sheet`

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
          If Not IsEmpty(Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1"))
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
          End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. Set first `Sheet` as the `[A1]` of the Sheet named `"Sheet2"`

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
          If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"))
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
          End If
   End Sub
   ```